# What is the main difference between yum remi and yum atomic repository?

Tags: linux, centos, yum

What is the main difference between yum remi and yum atomic repository ?

I have problem as i have installed them both and now they are conflicting in the

```
Yum update
```

I think they both serves the same set of packages isn't it ? what is the most suitable packages to use in a web-server ? and how to get rid of one of these repository ?

I think i have epel repository as well (which i think is the base repo for yum) isn't it ?

please help i am a new bee for the linux centos 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Remi repository aims mainly to provide the latest versions of the LAMP stack whereas Atomic repository provides much more. Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you probably shouldn't have both repositories enabled.

Neither Atomic or Remi should conflict with EPEL, so EPEL should co-exist peacefully with either.

One working option, if you really want to have both Atomic and Remi repositories for some odd reason, is to keep them both disabled by default (ie. having `enabled=0` in respective repository files, found in `/etc/yum.repos.d`) and only enable them when actually updating/installing something from them (use `--enablerepo=` switch with yum when installing/updating something from the repo in question).

For example, to install MySQL from Remi and Openvas from Atomic, you could do:

```
yum --enablerepo='*remi*' install mysql
yum --enablerepo='*tomic*' install openvas
```

This has the downside of having to update both MySQL and Openvas manually by enabling the respective repositories when running `yum update`. So it'd be best to re-think why you have both Remi and Atomic repositories enabled/available in the first place.

Comment: Thanks so much, Can you please also tell how to uninstall a repo i.e "atomic" ?

Comment: Easiest way is to just disable it by editing the file containing repo definitions in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. Do `grep -i atomic /etc/yum.repos.d/*` to find out which one contains it.